# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'coalesce'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

spark (2.4.5) is throwing the following error when trying to execute a select query similar to one shown below.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'coalesce'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 12
```

```
SELECT cast(coalesce(column1,'') as string) as id,cast(coalesce(column2,'2020-01-01') as date) as date1
from 4dea68ed921940e58f027e7146d495a4
```

Table 4dea68ed921940e58f027e7146d495a4 is a temp view created in spark from dataframe.
This error is happening intermittently only after certain processes. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share the sample input from `4dea68ed921940e58f027e7146d495a4` - `column1,column2`?

Comment: Just regular string data in column 1 like names or id's and date values in column2 like 2020-07-31. Both columns can have null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spark job is submitted through livy. Job contains two optional parameters and only one was provided. Providing all the parameters resolved the issue. Don't know why not providing an optional parameter caused this weird behavior but resolved the issue